# Why are simulation results drawing from scipy.stats.gumbel_l so different when random state is not None

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've written a very simple monte carlo simulation function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

def mc(ratings, sd, sample_size=1000, seed=None):
    samples = []
    for rating, dev in zip(ratings, sd):
        sample = st.gumbel_l.rvs(loc=rating, scale=dev, size=sample_size, random_state=seed)
        samples.append(sample)
    samples = np.array(samples)
    choice = (np.max(samples, axis=0) == samples).astype(int)
    probability = choice.sum(axis=1) / choice.sum().astype(float)
    return probability
```

The results don't make sense to me when using a random state != None.

For example, calling with and without seed below

```
> ratings = np.array([70., 72., 75.])
> sd = np.array([4., 8., 3.])
> mc(ratings, sd, sample_size=100000, seed=None)
> array([ 0.10797,  0.2908 ,  0.60123])
> mc(ratings, sd, sample_size=100000, seed=233831)
> array([ 0.     ,  0.16183,  0.83817])
```

These results are fairly consistent.  Am I missing something w.r.t how the rv_continuous implementations use the random state?  I'd expect that the results should be the same magnitude, just constant when using a random state != None.

Comment: Your `mc` function is reusing the same seed over and over for every RNG call.

Comment: @user2357112 that seems to fix the issue, though it's not clear to me why that would cause a problem.  I would think the only side effect of using the same seed would be that equivalent mu/std pairs would return the same exact results